# Can you upload contacts from a car [Kia] *to* an iPhone?

Tags: contacts, bluetooth, car-integration

Last night I accidentally deleted all my contacts from my phone. However, my contacts were synced via Bluetooth with my 2016 Kia Sportage. Is there a way to upload them back from the car and onto my phone, rather than trying to track them all down again? A cursory sweep of Google/Apple did not even answers if this is possible, let alone how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, it's highly unlikely that you will be able to send contacts back to your phone.**

While the iPhone (iPhone 4 and newer) [supports the Bluetooth Phone Book Access Profile (PBAP)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204387) the process is typically only one-way.

There are two roles in the PBAP profile:

- **Phone Book Server Equipment (PSE) role** - this role is for the device that contains the source phone-book objects; for example, a mobile phone.
- **Phone Book Client Equipment (PCE) role** - this role is for the device that retrieves phone-book objects from the PSE device; for example, a portable navigation device (PND).

Your iPhone acts as the server and the car radio acts as the client.

> Phone Book Download Feature
>
> This feature is used to download the entire content of a phone book
>   object. It is especially designed for devices with relatively large
>   storage capacity that are typically attempting to download and locally
>   store the entire phone book.
>
> Note that this feature is very basic. In particular, phone book
>   entries are delivered in ascending index order only. No sorting is
>   possible.

[image]
<sup>M = mandatory</sup>

In the [Bluetooth specification for Phone Book Access Profile](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview) (where the above info was sourced), there is no "push" function; only "pull."  This means for your iPhone to receive the Phone Book, it must change roles to being a client and your car radio to becoming a server.  I can't find any documentation that indicates iPhone supports this role or the Kia radios becoming a server.